# Flutter and Firebase: How can i receive data from function?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

i use the following function to fetch userData from Firestore:

```
Future<String>getRegisterUserData({String userID}) async {
Firestore.instance.collection("Users").document(userID).get().then(
  (datasnapshot) {
    if (datasnapshot.exists) {
      return datasnapshot.data['Email'];
    } else {
      return "Loading...";
    }
  },
);
}
```

I execute this function on my UserProfilePage like this:

```
_email = widget.firestore.getRegisterUserData(widget.userID).toString();
```

But i always get the print statement: Instance of 'Future' and not the saved email-address...

i also try this:

```
Future<String> getRegisterUserData({String userID}) async {
String email;
Firestore.instance.collection("Users").document(userID).get().then(
  (datasnapshot) {
    if (datasnapshot.exists) {
      email = datasnapshot.data['Email'];
    } else {
      email = "Loading...";
    }
  },
);
return email;
}
```

The Print Statement is always the same...

So where is my mistake? I want to display the Value of 'Email' on the UserProfilePage in a variable, or is my firestore function incorrect?

Thank you for our help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `await` keyword. But at a different place.

```
tempEmail = await widget.firestore.getRegisterUserData(widget.userID);
setState(() {
  _email = tempEmail;
});
// we don't need toString as getRegisterUserData itself is returning Future<String>
```

**Note** for using await: As we are using `await` the method/function which contains this should have a `async` in its signature.

Or you can use `then` block

```
widget.firestore.getRegisterUserData(widget.userID).then((email) {
   setState(() {
      _email = email;
   });
});
```

**Explanation:** `widget.firestore.getRegisterUserData(widget.userID)` is of type `Future<String>`. that's why it is printed as **Instance of 'Future'**. We have to convert the Future to String by `await` or by `then` block

**Using SharedPreferences:**

```
Future<String> getEmail() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String email = prefs.getString('email');
  if (email != null) {
    return email;
  } else {
    email = await widget.firestore.getRegisterUserData(widget.userID);
    prefs.setString('email', email); //update shared preferences
    return email;
  }
}

// usage (may be in initState)
 widget.getEmail().then((email) {
   setState(() {
     _email = email;
   })
 })
```

Comment: this doesn't work. The Email-Address will not be display as initialValue in a TextFormField. The initialValue will not be display in the moment...

Comment: We have to use `setState(() {})` to re-render once we get the data. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your answer... i have a last question: how can I save the email address without querying it from Firestore every time when the App is restarted or the Page is re-rendered? Can i use the initState-Method to do this? How does it work with apps like YouTube? The app must also temporarily cache the data

Comment: You can use `Shared_Preference` which is best for storing/fetching small data quickly. Refer https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences...

Comment: If my above answers are useful, can you upvote/accept?

Comment: Could you show me, how can i use it? (for example for the email-address) That would be really helpfully for me - thanks

Comment: Added one example. You can refer it

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Based on your information, you need a `FutureBuilder` in order to wait the response to build your widget:

```
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: getRegisterUserData(userID: "1234"),
    builder: (context, asyncsnapshot){
      return asyncsnapshot.hasData && asyncsnapshot.data != null ? TextFormField(
        initialValue: asyncsnapshot.data,
      ) : CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
  );
```

Comment: i added the await keyword, but the problem still exits... What can i do also, to solve the problem?

Comment: are you sure your collection and data exist?  could you return just a test String to ensure

Comment: yes, please look like this: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HMrLfXQ_rNWTJeAjpms2YXOao5WRT0Xs/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HMrLfXQ_rNWTJeAjpms2YXOao5WRT0Xs/view?usp=sharing) i don't get any error from firestore, when added the catchError Method...

Comment: could you print something : if (datasnapshot.exists) { after that ?

Comment: yes this works... but in my app i always see the String: Instance of 'Future<String>'
What does it mean?

Comment: please look like this screenshot: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1URMwprJJXoVPh7DhwhmAkoQ7A1x0LV43/view?usp=sharing)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1URMwprJJXoVPh7DhwhmAkoQ7A1x0LV43/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: ok looks like is working fine, print this : datasnapshot.data['Email']

Comment: `widget.firestore.getRegisterUserData(widget.userID)` is of type `Future<String>`. that's why it is **Instance of 'Future'**. We have to convert the Future<String> to String by `await` or by `then` block @diegovelper @Niklas

Comment: the email address will be print... so that works fine
On my ProfilePage, i added the function at this point: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/128_c-93XmDTjIc7laAYvHRrrl8WzZALG/view?usp=sharing)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/128_c-93XmDTjIc7laAYvHRrrl8WzZALG/view?usp=sharing]
And i get always the String: Instance of 'Future<String>'
@diegovelper

Comment: I added another answer below

Comment: I updated my answer :) , put futurebuilder inside your method buildEmailTextField

Comment: @diegoveloper sorry but your Update doesn't work... i always see the ProgressIndicator in my app, but not the email-address...

Comment: @Niklas are you returning the data, right ? update your code

Comment: I dont see a futurebuilder on that screen

Comment: @diegoveloper What do you mean with update your code? I reload and restart my app. please look at my Widget with the FutureBuilder: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpgyO2xpCnxuGfGUWg9ZonyQLL6TysHf/view?usp=sharing)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpgyO2xpCnxuGfGUWg9ZonyQLL6TysHf/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: thanks for your help and for your time :) 
Here is the (Firestore Function)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pd53ttpOLXO3DZ0kIOOpnMkVBQ-sXWKU/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: @diegoveloper oh sorry my mistake... thanks a lot it works now... i have a last question: How does this work with offline storage in Firestore? For example, how can I save the email address without querying it every time it is restarted? Thanks for your answer...

Comment: Firestore works in offline mode by default, so you wont have problems. Please mark the answer as accepted. If you have another question you could create a new issue. :)